# VERY slow connection when app is loading up

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I'm facing a very critical problem - I'm using Ionic platform to develop my app.
I have an object I need to make available as quickly as possible, so I'm trying to load as soon as I can.
However, I noticed that when trying to load it at the first chance I can - it loads VERY slow compared to loading it 2 seconds later.

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNQyPB

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','firebase'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var fb = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/");
  $scope.foo = foo;

  foo();
  function foo() {

    console.time('Done loading')
    ret = $firebaseObject(fb).$loaded(function() {
      console.timeEnd('Done loading');
    });

  }
});
```

Open the console and refresh the page - look at how long it takes to load when the function `foo()` is called immediately.
Now, remove the call to `foo()`, refresh it and click the body of the HTML which will initiate a call to `foo()`, look at how fast the object loaded comparing to the other way.
I will be happy to understand why it acts like that, and to find out a way around it.

Thank you
Guy

Comment: Your code looks minimal, there's nothing you can change about that to improve loading times. I get 500-600ms for the initial `console.time` here, <5ms for subsequents loads/clicks. That sounds pretty normal for me when connecting to firebase, so here too: there's nothing in your code that can improve that. Also realize that as David says: initial loading of the page resources takes time - about 3s on my tests. If you want to see where that time is going, check the Network tab of your Chrome devtools for a waterfall chart.

Comment: Let me know if you my answer helped :). It's good to keep the unanswered question queue clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePen is not the best place for page load testing of your app. The page has to load and then it loads a sandboxed `iframe`.

Also if this is an Ionic app, the entire set of assets will be downloaded onto the device. It will be instantly available to the user. So the only load time you'll be concerned with is the data load.

In your case you're doing a `console.time()`, I'm getting back around 300-400ms each time, which is pretty fast.

Comment: 2 more facts: 1. The time is slow even if I don't refresh the page but only change the code (which makes codepen to re-run the code). 2. I have the same problem with my app, only in a larger scale (I'm sometimes waiting about 30 seconds and sometimes 3). The 30s problem is something a little different which I couldn't create a code that re-produce that problem, so I'm starting by checking the loading time on start-up. So your answer still doesn't solve my mystery :)

Comment: Codepen doesn't just re-run the code, it does entire page load in the sandboxed iframe. This is why it's bad to use code pen for perf testing. Also measuring full page load has nothing to do with a Firebase connection.

Comment: The actual problem I'm trying to solve is the 30s loading time which is quite random on my app. It's sometimes 3seconds and sometimes 20-30s. If you have any ideas on how to test that, I'd be happy to hear. I've looked at the Network tab in Chrome and saw that it's purely waiting for firebase to return from the calls.

Comment: That was not apart of the original question. It's good to keep the questions simple and not diverge as it's hard for people to help. I recommend you select an answer here and then make another question where you clearly list your problem with screenshots of the network tab. If I could see what the calls are I could help with that :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if I can do that

Comment: Let me know where I can help!

Comment: How do you recommend to screenshot the network tab? It's extremely long after startup

Comment: I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906089/firebase-on-ionic-platform-occasionally-loading-slow

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely to do with the construction of a new Firebase reference and returning that once it's loaded. You're creating the new reference with

```
new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/");
```

That url takes 4.24s to load over my connection. Then in your `foo()` function you wait for that to load then execute another method like so

```
ret = $firebaseObject(fb).$loaded(function() {
      console.timeEnd('Done loading');
});
```

In total your codepen takes just over 5s over my connection, so the total time consists of waiting for your reference url to load plus the rest of the codepen page.

Comment: Waiting 5 seconds to open a connection is not acceptable. There must be something that can be done to improve that. Additionally - I only activate the timer right before I ask for the $firebaseObject itself, are you saying that it also waits to open a connection when it's being called upon the loading of the page?

Comment: If you absolutely have to wait for that url to load then you are constrained to the page load speed of that url. You might want to look at [extending services](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html) rather than `$loaded`

Comment: But `$loaded` is handling the async nature of the creation of your object so you won't block the event loop