# Firebase on Ionic platform occasionally loading SLOW

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I have an app which was built on ionic.
We're using Firebase to handle all our data, with no server for now.
There's a problem we've been experiencing for a long time now - the loading time of the app (exluding render time) is sometimes 4 seconds but sometimes take 30-60 seconds!
I was not able to reproduce this on purpose. Not on our app and not on a clean app.
However, I took snapshots of the network tab at one of the times it did happen, here they are (order is left to right): http://postimg.org/gallery/2aecew7lu/

You can see a long delay (45s?) at screenshot 8. After that the app was "released" and loaded.
I really hope you guys can help. Thank you

Comment: How much data is being loaded in each instance? What results do you get from [this curl command](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/b7aa394e0dadfd538c57) when the delays are occurring? What output do you get if you turn on Firebase debug logging with Firebase.enableLogging(true);? There are a couple hundred moving parts between your computer and the Firebase servers; need to isolate the problem a bit more.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @KishanB Yes, I moved to mongoDB :)